# Работа со структурами в Си

Tags: c, структуры

Есть вот такая достаточно простая программа на Си, она заведомо написана с ошибкой, я попытался ее найти, но не понял в чем суть. Я полагаю, что на консоль должно выводиться
str: 102
num: 1025

Выводится:
str: 1025
num: 1024

Почему после sprintf изменяется значение в num ? И почему в str записывается 4 цифры а не 3 в момент отладки внутри функции в str хранится '1','0','2', на выходе получаем 1025.
Пробовал менять спецификатор с %3d на %d результат не изменился.

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct
{
 char str[3];
 int num;
} NumberRepr;
void format(NumberRepr* number)
{
 sprintf(number->str, "%3d", number->num);
}
int main()
{
 NumberRepr number = { .num = 1025 };
 format(&number);
 printf("str: %s\n", number.str);
 printf("num: %d\n", number.num);
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: используйте другую функцию `snprintf(number->str,3, "%d", number->num);` и тогда будет вам две цифры *(третья буква будет конец строки `'\00'`)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что вы забыли о том, что С-строка (массив `char`) является строкой с завершающим нулевым символом. В результате, когда вы в 3 байта записываете строку `%3d`, четвертый символ - нулевой - записывается далее в память и портит следующее поле вашей структуры.

Вам надо указать иной, достаточный размер массива. Ну никак вы не поместите в 3 символа число 1024, например (для него нужно пять). Вобщем, не мелочитесь.

Хотя зачем вам одновременно держать одно и то же число в разном виде - не очень понимаю. Но тогда уж исходите из того, что int может быть и минус 2 миллиарда, т.е. реально нужен `char str[12]` как минимум...

Comment: судя по документации sprintf автоматически дописывает в последний символ массива символ конца строки '\0', но какой бы я спецификатор не использовал %d, %2d, %3d, значение записанное в str не изменяется, если указать еще больший размер, то значение в num меняется более радикально. Как правильно задать спецификатор, чтобы переписать из num в str три цифры ? Размер str я поменял на 5 только тогда перестает затрагивать num, потому что в нем 4-х значное число - это я понял

Comment: Вам надо указать иной, достаточный размер массива! Ну никак вы не поместите в 3 символа число 1024, например. Нужно пять. Вобщем, не мелочитесь :) Хотя зачем вам одновременно держать одно и то же число в разном виде - не очень понимаю. Но тогда уж исходите из того, что `int` может быть и минус 2 миллиарда, т.е. реально нужен `char str[12]` как минимум...

Answer (score 1):

Видимо вы не ознакомились с [документацией](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) к функции `sprintf`. Число 3 в строке с форматом задает *минимальную* ширину поля. Соответственно для печати числа 1025 что с форматом `%3d`, что с форматом `%d`, требуется 4 + 1 байт. В любом случае происходит переполнение буфера. Вместо этого следовало использовать функцию `snprintf` и указать размер входящего буфера. При этом также следует не забыть проверить возвращаемое значение на предмет ошибки или усечения вывода:

```
void format(NumberRepr* number)
{
    int const result = snprintf(number->str, 3, "%d", number->num);
    if (result <= 0)
    {
        printf("snprintf failed: %d\n", result);
        abort();
    }
    if ((3 - 1) < result)
    {
        printf("snprintf truncated output of length %d to %d bytes\n", result, (3 - 1));
    }
}
```

[online compiler](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,selection:(endColumn:15,endLineNumber:17,positionColumn:15,positionLineNumber:17,selectionStartColumn:15,selectionStartLineNumber:17,startColumn:15,startLineNumber:17),source:%27%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstdlib.h%3E%0A%0Atypedef+struct%0A%7B%0A+char+str%5B3%5D%3B%0A+int+num%3B%0A%7D+NumberRepr%3B%0Avoid+format(NumberRepr*+number)%0A%7B%0A++++int+const+result+%3D+snprintf(number-%3Estr,+3,+%22%25d%22,+number-%3Enum)%3B%0A++++if+(result+%3C%3D+0)%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++printf(%22snprintf+failed:+%25d%5Cn%22,+result)%3B%0A++++++++abort()%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++if+((3+-+1)+%3C+result)%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++printf(%22snprintf+truncated+output+of+length+%25d+to+%25d+bytes%5Cn%22,+result,+(3+-+1))%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A+NumberRepr+number+%3D+%7B+.num+%3D+1025+%7D%3B%0A+format(%26number)%3B%0A+printf(%22str:+%25s%5Cn%22,+number.str)%3B%0A+printf(%22num:+%25d%5Cn%22,+number.num)%3B%0A+return+0%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:executor,i:(argsPanelShown:%271%27,compilationPanelShown:%270%27,compiler:cg113,compilerOutShown:%270%27,execArgs:%27%27,execStdin:%27%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27--std%3Dc11+-Wall+-Wextra%27,source:1,stdinPanelShown:%271%27,tree:%271%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Executor+x86-64+gcc+11.3+(C,+Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:50,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)

Еще размер буфера следует не хардкодить, а определять через макрос, но это уже другой вопрос.